# Unknown runtime error when running macro

Tags: excel, vbscript, excel.application, vba

I needed a way to schedule automatically opening an Excel file, refresh the contents then save and close it.

I have done this before but I can no longer open the file as opening it causes the macro that refreshes then saves and closes the file to run.

I considered VBScript after trying several ways of doing it. I found this code on here.

```
Dim objExcel, objWorkbook 
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\...\Finances.xlsm")
objExcel.Visible = True
objExcel.Run "Refresh"
objExcel.Quit

Set objWorkbook = Nothing
Set objExcel = Nothing

WScript.Quit
```

The VBScript code opens the Excel file and triggers the macro `Refresh` inside. The macro refreshes the data then saves and closes the file.

But I'm getting the following error despite the code seeming to run ok.

[image: "Unknown Runtime Error" in line 5]

Comment: Does the Excel Macro "refresh" maybe have a line of code which closes the Excel Workbook? If so, then your VBS gets the runtime error because it was waiting for the `objExcel.Run "Refresh"` to be completed which in turn closed the Excel WorkBook

Comment: You need to show the macro code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want anything to run automatically when you open the workbook, put the line

```
objExcel.EnableEvents = False
```

before you open the workbook. You could set it back to `True` later if you need to. You should still be able to run `Refresh`. Whether or not that will fix your unknown error, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You are quitting the [excel.application](/questions/tagged/excel.application) object without closing the `objWorkbook` open workbook. Saved or not, this is going to generate an error crashing out of the open workbook.